# show that E(Y ) = rE(X_1)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

For $Y= X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_r$, with the X's being independent and identically distributed random variables, I'm asked to prove that $E(Y) = rE(X_1)$

All I could do is show $(M_X(t))^r = (E( e^{tx}))^r = E(e^{tx_1}) E(e^{tx_2})  ... E(e^{tx_r}) = E( e^{tx_1} e^{tx_2} ... e^{tx_r}) = E(e^{ty}) = M_Y(t) $

Can anyone help/guide me? Thanks

Comment: This is something similar to Wald's equation if I'm not wrong. Wiki has the proof

Comment: @makina $r$ isn't random.

Comment: hence the "similar"

Comment: @bluemuse  Before studying Moment Generating Functions you must have learned that expectation is linear. This question hardly requires  a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use moment generating functions (not all distributions have them, but assuming $X$ does) then you can say

$$M'_Y(t) = \frac{d}{dt} (M_X(t))^r = r (M_X(t))^{r-1} M'_X(t)$$

and since $M_X(0)=1$ and $M'_X(0)= E[X]$ you can say $$E[Y] = M'_Y(0) = r  M'_X(0)=rE[X]$$

Comment: Thank you, we got this homework after studying moment generating functions so I figured I had to use them. I forgot about $ M'_X(0) = E[X]$ ! Thanks

Comment: they are iid. Isn't sufficient to say that because they are iid then $E[X_i]=E[X_1]$ hence E[Y]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+...+E[X_r] = E[X_1]+E[X_1]+...+E[X_r]=rE[X_1]?

Comment: @k.dkhk - what you say is true in general, independent or not.  Can you prove it?  With independent random variables a simple alternative approach comes from characteristic functions or (if they exist) moment generating functions.